# Edit value to database through custom admin, Opencart 2.0

Tags: php, mysql, admin, opencart2.x

I am trying to make an easy form in OpenCart 2.0.1.1 that stores the values in the database.

I have done a custom admin page where i will have some extensions i make of my own. This was the easy part.

I have made the form and the column in the database, this is working fine, i get the values and it is showing in the textarea inside the admin. But the issue is when i am trying to edit the texts. When i change the value of the textarea and hit save it just dissapears! and the column in the database is gone.

My controller file:

admin/controller/ekomet/design.php

```
<?phpclass ControllerEkometdesign extends Controller {
private $error = array();

public function index() {
    $this->load->language('ekomet/design');

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    $this->load->model('setting/setting');

    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
        $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('design_name', $this->request->post);
        }

    $data['button_save'] = $this->language->get('button_save');
    $data['button_cancel'] = $this->language->get('button_cancel');

    $data['tab_general'] = $this->language->get('tab_general');

    $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('common/dashboard', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
    );

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_stores'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('ekomet/design', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
    );

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('ekomet/design', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
    );

    if (isset($this->session->data['success'])) {
        $data['success'] = $this->session->data['success'];

        unset($this->session->data['success']);
    } else {
        $data['success'] = '';
    }

    $data['action'] = $this->url->link('ekomet/design', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');

    $data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('ekomet/design', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');

    $data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];

    $settings = $this->model_setting_setting->getSetting('design_name');

    if (isset($this->request->post['config_ekomet_name'])) {
        $data['config_ekomet_name'] = $this->request->post['config_ekomet_name'];
    } else {
        $data['config_ekomet_name'] = $this->config->get('config_ekomet_name');
    }

    $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
    $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('ekomet/design.tpl', $data));
}

protected function validate() {
    if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'ekomet/design')) {
        $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
    }

    if ($this->error && !isset($this->error['warning'])) {
        $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_warning');
    }

    return !$this->error;
}}
```

I have looked through the setting.php controller and i do want to use the setting table in my database to store my values (no need to invent the wheel again). As i said above. It do pass the values from the database. But i can't update it.

My template file:

admin/view/template/ekomet/design.tpl

```
          <div class="form-group required">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-ekomet-name">E-komet namn</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="config_ekomet_name" value="<?php echo $config_ekomet_name; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_ekomet_name; ?>" id="input-ekomet-name" class="form-control" />
              <?php if ($error_ekomet_name) { ?>
              <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_ekomet_name; ?></div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I have not made my own model file because i want to use the one who is connected to setting. Do i need to make my own model to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong prefix for code and key field

Make sure if `code = abc` then `key = abc_def`

Replace

```
 $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('design_name', $this->request->post);
```

With

```
 $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('config', $this->request->post);
```

So that it will be `code = config` and `key = config_ekomet_name`

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for your quick answer, i tried to do what you said. When i tried to make it with a predefined column in database it worked good like before, but as soon i saved and changed the value it deleted all my "config" keys in settings table and i got the error message in admin: (Warning: fopen(/home/u/u6144172/www/system/logs/): failed to open stream: Is a directory in /home/u/u6144172/www/system/library/log.php on line 6). I also tried without predefined column, same result. Do you know what i am missing?

Comment: Can say tho it worked like a charm for my column, but it deleted all the other config columns hehe.

Comment: I'm sorry mate (I feel stupid now). I just renamed code + key to something else and it works perfectly now, Thanks alot for the help!

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasted for hours until I red your answer